# R: optim() gives different result when values are passed as a vector

Tags: r, optimization

**Summary**

In my setup, I start with a three-point trajectory in a given, delimited space. I am passing the points' x-coordinates to a penalty function, `trj_points_penalty_fun` which calculates a penalty for the trajectory as the sum of:

1. the total trajectory length, given the three points, and a fixed start and endpoint
2. the sum of a bivariate density's values for those points. The bivariate is centered in the same delimited space and has fixed standard deviations and correlation coefficient.

The function `trj_points_penalty_fun` is built in such a way that the points' x-coordinates are passed one by one. I then optimize the function using `optim()`, and the result gives me the x-coordinates for which the penalty is minimum (I am keeping the y-coordinates fixed).

The problem is that when I pass the points to the penalty function as a *vector*, as in `trj_vector_min_pen_fun`, `optim()` gives me a different answer compared to the answer given when I pass the points one by one.

**Reproducible example**

See the following example. I apologize for the length; I tried to simplify the setup but then I could not reproduce the error.

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
```

The following function, `points_distance`, is used to calculate the length of the total trajectory

```r
points_distance <- function(x) {
  x$distance <- NA
  for (i in 1:(nrow(x) - 1)) {
    x$distance[i] <- pointDistance(c(x[, 1][i], x[, 2][i]),
      c(x[, 1][i + 1], x[, 2][i + 1]),
      lonlat = FALSE
    )
  }

  # Return output
  return(x)
}
```

The following function, `add_start_end`, adds a fixed start and endpoint to the trajectory's coordinates:

```r
add_start_end <- function(points) {
  points_plus_fixed_start <- rbind(c(0,-3),points)
  points_plus_fixed_start_end <- rbind(points_plus_fixed_start, c(0,3))
  return (points_plus_fixed_start_end)
}
```

The following is a *constructor function* that creates `trj_points_penalty_fun`, a penalty function in which the points are passed one by one.
In the constructor, the bivariate parameters and the y-coordinates are passed in as `data`. The x-coordinates are passed in as three single values:

```r
MAKE_trj_points_penalty_fun <- function(data, fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)) {
  params <- fixed
  function(p) {
    params[!fixed] <- p

    mu <- c(0, 0)
    mu[1] <- data[1]
    mu[2] <- data[2]
    sd1 <- data[3]
    sd2 <- data[4]
    rho <- data[5]
    lambda <- data[6]
    y_coord1 <- data[7]
    y_coord2 <- data[8]
    y_coord3 <- data[9]

    #create vector with three points for looping.
    y_coords <- c(y_coord1, y_coord2, y_coord3)

    tot_density <- 0

    # calculates the bivariate density for each point

    for (i in seq(seq_along(params))) {   # seq(1:length(params))

      Q <- (params[i] - mu[1])^2 / sd1^2 + (y_coords[i] - mu[2])^2 / sd2^2 -
        2 * rho * (params[i] - mu[1]) * (y_coords[i] - mu[2]) / (sd1 * sd2)

      density <- 1 / (2 * pi * sd1 * sd2 * sqrt(1 - rho^2)) * exp(-Q / (2 * (1 - rho^2)))

      tot_density <- tot_density + density
      tot_density
    }

    points <- data.frame(
            x = c(params[1], params[2], params[3]),
            y = c(y_coord1, y_coord2, y_coord3)
    )
    segment <- add_start_end(points)
    dist <- points_distance(segment)
    trj <- sum(dist$distance, na.rm = TRUE)

    # tot penalty

    tot <- lambda * (trj / 10) + (1 - lambda) * (tot_density / 0.1591549)
    return(tot)

  }
}
```

Here I create `trj_points_penalty_fun` using the constructor:

```r
trj_points_penalty_fun <- MAKE_trj_points_penalty_fun(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.5,-2.5, 0, 2.5))
```

Now we pass in the x-coordinates:

```r
trj_points_penalty_fun(c(0.5, 1, 0.5))
#> [1] 0.6677013
```

Optimizing the function...

```r
optim(par = c(0, 0, 0), trj_points_penalty_fun)$par
```

...gives the following result:

```r
#> [1] 0.7146940 2.4769463 0.7148109
```

Now the other case, in which the trajectory points are passed as a vector:

```r
# Toy trajectory 
toy_trj_vs <- data.frame(
  x <-  c(0.5, 1, 0.5),
  y <- c(-2.5, 0, 2.5)
)

x_coord <- toy_trj_vs[,1]
y_coord <- toy_trj_vs[,2]

vect_f <-  rep(F, length(x_coord))
```

The following is a *constructor function* that creates `trj_vector_penalty_fun`, a penalty function in which the
points' coordinates are passed as vectors.

```r
MAKE_trj_vector_penalty_fun <- function(data_vs, fixed_y_coord, fixed_vs =
  vect_f) {
  params_vs <- fixed_vs
  function(p_vs) {
    params_vs[!fixed_vs] <- p_vs
    mu_vs <- c(0, 0)
    mu_vs[1] <- data_vs[1]
    mu_vs[2] <- data_vs[2]
    sd1_vs <- data_vs[3]
    sd2_vs <- data_vs[4]
    rho_vs <- data_vs[5]
    lambda_vs <- data_vs[6]

    tot_density_vs <- 0

    # calculates the bivariate density for each point

    for (i in seq(seq_along(params_vs))) {
      Q_vs <- (params_vs[i] - mu_vs[1])^2 / sd1_vs^2 + (fixed_y_coord[i] - mu_vs[2])^2 / sd2_vs^2 -
        2 * rho_vs * (params_vs[i] - mu_vs[1]) * (fixed_y_coord[i] - mu_vs[2]) / (sd1_vs * sd2_vs)
      density_vs <- 1 / (2 * pi * sd1_vs * sd2_vs * sqrt(1 - rho_vs^2)) * exp(-Q_vs / (2 * (1 -
        rho_vs^2)))
      tot_density_vs <- tot_density_vs + density_vs
      tot_density_vs
    }

    segment_vs <- add_start_end(toy_trj_vs)
    dist_vs <- points_distance(segment_vs)
    trj_vs <- sum(dist_vs$distance, na.rm = TRUE)

    # total penalty

    tot_vs <- lambda_vs * (trj_vs / 10) + (1 - lambda_vs) * (tot_density_vs / 0.1591549)

    # return(c(trj_vs, tot_vs))
    return(tot_vs)
  }
}
```

```r
trj_vector_penalty_fun <- MAKE_trj_vector_penalty_fun(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.5), y_coord)
trj_vector_penalty_fun(x_coord)
#> [1] 0.6677013
initial_vector <- c(0, 0, 0)
optim(par = initial_vector, trj_vector_penalty_fun)$par
```

The results should be the same as before, but they are different:

```r
#> [1] -34.933333  42.885185   9.392593
```

I have checked all the output values of the two functions, they look exactly the same.

Using the debugger, I stepped inside `optim()` in the two cases, and the output looks the same, except for one point:

`optim(par = c(0, 0, 0), trj_points_penalty_fun)$par` gives `function = 142`

`optim(par = initial_vector, trj_vector_penalty_fun)$par` gives `function = 46`

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Can you reduce your example by at least 50%? That would probably help you answer your own question, but if not, someone else might be more inclined to have a look.

Comment: I tried, but I need both functions (the trajectory function and the bivariate density function) to reproduce the error. I wouldn't know what to cut. I could make the segment shorter, or get away with the constructor, but that would save only a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in how the total trajectory, `trj_vs`, was calculated inside `MAKE_trj_vector_penalty_fun`.

I was doing the following:

```r
(...)
segment_vs <- add_start_end(toy_trj_vs)
dist_vs <- points_distance(segment_vs)
trj_vs <- sum(dist_vs$distance, na.rm = TRUE)
(...)
```

Meaning that I was referring to constant values set outside the function. Instead, I need to calculate the trajectory using the values that I am passing into the function:

```r
(...)
toy_trj_vs_inside_fun <- data.frame(
                    x <- params_vs,
                    y <- fixed_y_coord
                    )

segment_vs <- add_start_end(toy_trj_vs_inside_fun)
dist_vs <- points_distance(segment_vs)
trj_vs <- sum(dist_vs$distance, na.rm = TRUE)
(...)
```

Now everything works as expected:

```r
MAKE_trj_vector_penalty_fun <- function(data_vs, fixed_y_coord, fixed_vs =
  vect_f) {
  params_vs <- fixed_vs
  function(p_vs) {
    params_vs[!fixed_vs] <- p_vs
    mu_vs <- c(0, 0)
    mu_vs[1] <- data_vs[1]
    mu_vs[2] <- data_vs[2]
    sd1_vs <- data_vs[3]
    sd2_vs <- data_vs[4]
    rho_vs <- data_vs[5]
    lambda_vs <- data_vs[6]

    tot_density_vs <- 0

    # calculates the bivariate density for each point

    for (i in seq(seq_along(params_vs))) {
      Q_vs <- (params_vs[i] - mu_vs[1])^2 / sd1_vs^2 + (fixed_y_coord[i] - mu_vs[2])^2 / sd2_vs^2 -
        2 * rho_vs * (params_vs[i] - mu_vs[1]) * (fixed_y_coord[i] - mu_vs[2]) / (sd1_vs * sd2_vs)
      density_vs <- 1 / (2 * pi * sd1_vs * sd2_vs * sqrt(1 - rho_vs^2)) * exp(-Q_vs / (2 * (1 -
        rho_vs^2)))
      tot_density_vs <- tot_density_vs + density_vs
      tot_density_vs
    }
    toy_trj_vs_inside_fun <- data.frame(
                    x <- params_vs,
                    y <- fixed_y_coord
                    )

    segment_vs <- add_start_end(toy_trj_vs_inside_fun)
    dist_vs <- points_distance(segment_vs)
    trj_vs <- sum(dist_vs$distance, na.rm = TRUE)

    # total penalty

    tot_vs <- lambda_vs * (trj_vs / 10) + (1 - lambda_vs) * (tot_density_vs / 0.1591549)

    # return(c(trj_vs, tot_vs))
    return(tot_vs)
  }
}

trj_vector_penalty_fun <- MAKE_trj_vector_penalty_fun(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.5), y_coord)
trj_vector_penalty_fun(x_coord)
#> [1] 0.6677013

initial_vector <- c(0, 0, 0)
optim(par = initial_vector, trj_vector_penalty_fun)$par
```

Results:

```r
#> [1] 0.7146940 2.4769463 0.7148109
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>